# google api service account Access user task list

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, service-accounts

I have a gmail user and I created a service account with that user.

The user itself has tasklists and I want to access them via the service account.

However, the lists do not seem to be linked to the service account. I only get one empty list when querying the tasks api with the service account authentication token.

Do I need to somehow tell it to access the actual user tasks?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an OAuth client to access a user's task lists, not a service account: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent